# AltGr button seems to be disabled

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, alt

I'm working with a Windows 10 machine.

I'm using quite some keyboard shortcuts so my problem can be related with a wrong key combination: since this morning my keyboard button <kbd>AltGr</kbd> does not work anymore, I need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> in order to type something like (`@`-sign in e-mail addresses, backticks,...).

Does anybody know how to enable this keyboard button again?

Comment: ALT-GR is part of a keyboard language. If it doesn't work, then you need to alter your keyboard layout language to a different one, for example United States International. If it worked before, then you likely switched to a different layout. The shortcut key for that is CTRL-SPACE or ALT-SHIFT

Answer (score 0):

In this post there is a similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482392/altgr-key-not-working-instead-i-have-to-use-ctrlaltgr

They talk about using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried both shortcuts keys (Ctrl+Enter and Alt+Enter), and none of them actually works.

Comment: Close all open remote desktop connections and try again

Comment: It was indeed an RDC open that blocked the key, thanks